# Is there a Python data structure which is sortable and searchable?

Tags: python, list, data-structures, priority-queue

I'm using python to manage a queue of strings to process. It has a couple of requirments:

- Each string is matched to a priority and is processed based solely on that value.
- Strings can be added to this queue dynamically but no duplicate Strings are allowed in the queue. If a duplicate is submitted then it must be identified and ignored.

So is there any python datatype that will allow something like this? Or do I have to write my own?

If there isn't a native one then, I'm thinking of maintaining two structures.

1. A [heapq](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html) which will maintain the strings and their priority
2. A [list](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) which maintains a hash of the strings to check whether the string is already stored

As long as these do not fall out of sync it should solve the problem.

Comment: why not a dictionary? or ordereddict?

Comment: @utdmr: Sorting a dictionary by values is not that great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like a reasonable approach. I would use a `set` instead of a `list` since it has more efficient membership checking and you don't need to maintain order (since you do it in the heapq)

Comment: Definitely should use a `set`

Answer (score 2):

An ordered dictionary may be of help.

See this page ([an ordered dictionary](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/odict.html#other-use-cases)) where it states:

> The ordered dictionary keeps keys in insertion order. This is sometimes called a created order dictionary.
>
> There are potential use cases for dictionaries that keep their keys in order, but the ordering being based on other criteria.
>
> You are free **to change the order** using the **setkeys** method, but you may prefer a dictionary that used these different criteria. For example you might need a dictionary that kept keys in order of the last accessed key.

Comment: So I would have the priority of the strings as the keys and the values as the strings, and I can then sort based on the value of the keys? How would I check whether the string already exists in the queue?